# Can't pass a django variable into javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I cannot pass a django variable into a javascript file. The way I'm trying to pass it right now is through my base.html file through a script tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var user = '{{ request.user }}'
  var csrftoken = {% csrf_token %}
  var x = 5

</script>
```

The script tag shown is near the top of the file (so the page loads), this information is supposed to be processed through this javascript function in a file called cart.js:

```
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

for (i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
  updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    var productId = this.dataset.product
    var action = this.dataset.action
    console.log(x)  //the variable from the base.html file
    console.log('productId:', productId, 'Action:', action)
  
    updateUserOrder(productId, action)
    

  })
}
```

However in console the error reads:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (cart.js:7)
```

the view using base.html when this error occurs is a function based view.
Thanks!

Comment: When you see the html Django outputs, do you see `{{ request.user }}` actually filled with data?
I doubt the problem is django related, as in your exemple the variable `x` does not depend of any template rendering. How is your `cart.js` file loaded?

Comment: Why don't you add the variable you need to pass to a data html attribute and you get it in your cart.js file?